# shulchan aruch translation in english

Tags: discussion

I answered to a question [If a woman, whose husband is away, becomes pregnant, is she assumed to be adulterous?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/62069/if-a-woman-whose-husband-is-away-becomes-pregnant-is-she-assumed-to-be-adulte) citing a psak of the shulchan aruch.

I was asked to translate this citation to english. Is there in the web a ready available translation of the shulchan aruch to english which i may use? I am not a native english speaker and i fear that i won't make the translation exact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site is an English-language site and a good answer will explain, in English, everything that's necessary for answering the question. However, that doesn't (in my opinion) mean that you need to translate a long passage of *Shulchan Aruch* that answers the question: it's sufficient to paraphrase/summarize it — which you did admirably in [your answer](//judaism.stackexchange.com/a/62070). So I don't think you need to worry about including a translation also.

Even if a translation is desired as well, don't think that you have to be the one to provide it. Stack Exchange answers are, by design, [editable by others](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) "to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it" and "to add related resources", and someone else may come along to add in the translation.

If you *do* want to add in the translation yourself, well, there's [Sefaria's](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.4.14?lang=he-en).

Comment: There's also a translation project in progress (and in need of help) at https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:Shulchan_Aruch